# Why does it shows "fatal: Too many arguments."?

Tags: python-3.x, git, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to clone the repo at my folder but I am getting this error although I succeed to create folder labeling in folder named Tesnsorflow but then it's giving me this error **fatal: Too many arguments.** instead of clone the repo

```
LABELIMG_PATH = os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'labelimg') 
if not os.path.exists(LABELIMG_PATH):
  !mkdir {LABELIMG_PATH}
  !git clone https: // github.com/tzutalin/labelImg {LABELIMG_PATH}
```

I am tryig to clone the repo using

```
!git clone https: // github.com/tzutalin/labelImg {LABELIMG_PATH}
```

I cannot do much to solve this as I am a beginner at this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that strange syntax for executing shell command from Python.

But the URL should be be definitively ONE argument, not three

```
https: // github.com/tzutalin/labelImg    // not good
https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg      // should be better :-)
```

Comment: It works :)  small mistake ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

It was my mistake in URL `https: // github.com/tzutalin/labelImg` instead of this we have to type `https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg`  and also have to add `.git` so final URL is `https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg.git`